# What is the Canonical Metric for Investment? (U.S.)

Tags: investment, national-accounts

I'm currently taking a run-of-the-mill Intermediate Macro class and have coursework which asks to produce a vis that tracks U.S. Investment from 1970-2014. What is the salient/canonical National Accounts metric for this?

At present I'm using Gross Domestic Private Investment from the FRED database, but am uneasy about what exactly "Private" means/whether that excludes anything I need to include.

The class itself is mostly modelling so refers to investment as just 'I', not any specific metric so there's nothing from the actual class content for me to go on.

Comment: This seems to depend on what the assignment means by the word investment.